# ld.exe cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, linker, libraries

I have recently bought a book on OpenGL and am trying to follow the examples, but I can't get to seem OpenGL to work.

For example, it gives me the error:

> ld.exe||cannot find -lGL|.

My compiler is `GNU-GCC` `MinGW` on with the IDE `Code::Blocks`, and my OS is Windows 7 64 bit. I have linked the libraries: `opengl32`, `glu32`, `glut32`, and in other linker options I have: `-lmingw32` `-lSDLmain` `-lSDL`, because this was advised on the `code::blocks` wiki.

I have some experience with C++, but not at all when it comes to linking, and setting up the compiler, because this used to go quite automatic.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you rephrase this in terms of a question? What exactly are you trying to do with OpenGL? How are you invoking it?
The more descriptive information is, the easier it will be for people to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag `-lGL` is to link to the opengl library, but on Windows the opengl library is called `opengl32`, not libgl. So you shouldn't use `-lGL` and if you're already linking in opengl32 then that should be all you need.

Comment: It seems I need to do something. I can't seem to find where I am using `lGL`, I have this in my file: `#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>` but removing the statement `#inlcude <GL/gl.h>` doesn't solve anything, nor does it remove or add an error.

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with includes. You do need to include GL/gl.h, anyway. Since presumably you already checked the linker flags I'm not sure where else you would check since I'm not familiar with your build system. Look around and try to get more verbose output is all I can say.

Answer (score 4):

`-lGL` is the linkage option used on *nix systems. On Windows you should use `-lopengl32`

Comment: So what should I change? If I put `-lopengl32` in my linker settings that doesn't change anything. I don't really have a clue what to do. As I stated before, when it comes to setting up my compiler I don't really know that much.

Comment: @user1816721: Well, omit the -lGL, because that's nonexistend on a Windows system; however it may be, that one of the library includes errorneous adds a linking `#pragma` pulling in libGL.so (-lGL).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the library and include folder permission set to read-only, I am currently having the same issues but i am working with my SFML compilation, I solved it by setting the linker to the exact lib file not the folder, you may try the same solution